# Automatically add 15 minute reminder to event calendar downloads

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, reminder

We have many events on our SharePoint site and users who want to attend click an 'Add to my calendar' link to download an `.ics` file calendar invite, which they can then save into their personal outlook calendar.

At present the reminder is set to 'None' for all invites so people are forgetting to attend the events - how do I change it by default to 15 minutes, or just anything that will remind people to attend?

I can't see how to change it in the settings. There are some suggestions of creating a workflow but that seems to be for specific events, whereas I want the default to be a 15-minute reminder before the event.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading, have you tried to [sync to Outlook](https://sharepointmaven.com/sync-sharepoint-with-outlook/)? It may be much more easier to handle events for end users.

Comment: Thanks for responding - if I have understood correctly, from that explanation it looks like everything in Sharepoint calendar would then appear in the users' Outlook calendar and I only want those calendar events that they choose to appear. There are many optional events and thousands of potential users.